# Can't execute form when I put javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my PHP code and the same file I put javascript but then when I input the javascript code, my form in php will not execute to add in database. (I don't put the insert code here.)

```
echo '<form action="$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];" method="POST">';

        echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';

            $t = mysqli_query($connect, $q);

                echo '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    echo "<select name='start' class='form-control'required  >";
                            echo '<option value="">Select Location</option>';
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            unset($loc_name);
                            $loc_name = $row['loc_name'];

                            echo '<option value="'.$loc_name.'">'.$loc_name.'</option>'; }
                    echo "</select><br>";
               echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    echo '<select name="status" class="form-control" required >';
                        echo '<option value="">Status</option>';
                        echo '<option>Priority</option>';
                        echo '<option>Not Priority</option>';
                    echo '</select><br>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    echo '<input type="number" name="pieces" placeholder="Piece(s) of Item" class="form-control" required />';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    echo '<input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" required />';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<center><button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></center>';
                echo '</form>';
```

And here's my javascript code with the php

```
                echo '
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputText">Total Price</label>
                        <input type="text" name="totalval" class="form-control" id="totalval" onchange="updateDue()">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputText">Initial Deposit</label>
                        <input type="text" name="inideposit" class="form-control" id="inideposit" onchange="updateDue()">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputText">Outstanding Dues</label>
                        <input type="text" name="remainingval" class="form-control" id="remainingval">
                    </div>';


echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateDue() {

    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalval").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inideposit").value);

    // to make sure that they are numbers
    if (!total) { total = 0; }
    if (!val2) { val2 = 0; }

    var ansD = document.getElementById("remainingval");
    ansD.value = total - val2;
}
</script>';
```

Comment: You need script tags around function updateDue().

Comment: is your js Functions declared before ( at the top of the page ) or after ( at the bottom of the page ) of those HTML? unless you are using document events (which you are not doing), otherwise JS needs to be initiated after DOM is rendered.

Comment: it's after the php code, at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose you javascript inside script tags. Example

```
echo '<script>
 function updateDue() {

     var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalval").value);
     var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inideposit").value);

     // to make sure that they are numbers
     if (!total) { total = 0; }
     if (!val2) { val2 = 0; }

     var ansD = document.getElementById("remainingval");
     ansD.value = total - val2;
    }
</script> ';
```